# Adding C compiler MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I add C compilers to MATLAB 7.9.0(R2009b)? I tried `mex -setup` to view the supported compilers, but I am getting this:

```
**>> mex -setup
Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 

[0] None**
```

If anyone knows the solution, please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compilers do you have installed on your computer?

Comment: I usually use [mexopts.sh](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) to specify the compiler by adding something like "CXX=pathtog++" and "CC=pathtocc" to the file in "~/.matlab/R2011a/mexopts.sh". Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the supported compilers for 2009b.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2009b/index.html

If you have one of these installed at a default location, then the command you posted will find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you're using a supported compiler say no (n) when asked if you want mex to find the compiler. If your compiler is not in the default location say no at the next prompt with the defualt location. Enter the path of the folder with your compiler; make sure to use single quotes around the path.